# How can I create a search filter by title in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good night,
I have the following code from a Json api to create a bookstore with Vue.js, here is the code. 
I dont know what is the problem with "computed".

```
new Vue({
  el: "#vue-app",
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Ubiqum Bookstore",
      books: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getAPI('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h3vb3');
  },
  methods: {
    getAPI() {
      axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h3vb3')
        .then(response => {
          (this.books = response.data.books)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log("No found!")
        })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    booksFilter: function() {
      var textSearch = this.textSearch;
      return this.books.filter(function(el) {
        return el.books.toLowerCase().indexOf(textSearch.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      });
    }
  },
})
```

I want to know why the computed doesnt work for me.
In HTML I have,

```
<div id="list-countries" v-if="booksFilter && booksFilter.length">
    <div class="panel panel-default" v-for="book of booksFilter">
<input id="input-search" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="search" placeholder='Search...'>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems to me your books are objects (when looking at https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h3vb3). So you probably have to do: return el.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(textSearch.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || el.descripcion.toLowerCase().indexOf(textSearch.toLowerCase());

Comment: what is this.textSearch supposed to be? looks like you never actually declare it in the data.

Also looks like you are v-modeling on "search" which again is never defined in the data.

I suggest you set textSearch in the data first ` data() {
      return {
          title : "Ubiqum Bookstore",
          books: [],
          textSearch: ' '
      }`

and then in the template you should do v-model="textSearch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like established in comment, what is `this.searchText`, you are using `search` in the template, so that is what should be used. Then as also established, your array contains objects, so based on what you want to filter by (maybe `titulo` like in other answer?). I would use `includes()` to check if the value entered in input is found in `titulo` (again, if that is what you want to search). All in all, I suggest the following:

```js
data() {
  return {
    title: "Ubiqum Bookstore",
    books: [],
    search: '' // add this!
  }
},
// .....
computed: {
  booksFilter: function() {
    return this.books.filter(book => {
      return book.titulo.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

and template:

```html
<div v-if="booksFilter && booksFilter.length">
  <div v-for="book of booksFilter">
    <p>{{book.titulo}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a **[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-ives-d6no7)** to play with.

Answer (score 0):

you did wrong in many places

```
    computed: {
            booksFilter: function() {
              var textSearch = this.textSearch;// textSearch not exist in data or in v-model, so it must containing invalid data
              return this.books.filter(function(el) {
//for the below line el.books not exist, if you want to match with title then you should change this like el.titulo
                return el.books.toLowerCase().indexOf(textSearch.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
              });
            }
         }
```

By the way, if you want to use your title value from data model ,then you need to change the computed property like this:

```
computed: {
    booksFilter: function() {
      return this.books.filter(el => {
        return el.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.title.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I get 'error during evaluation', I need an v-if in the html?